# Do something when all dynamically created images have loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, asynchronous, jquery-events, jquery-deferred

What I'm trying to do is create a dynamic wall of images.

What I'm doing is this:

1. Call an API to get some response. Create an array of objects based on response
2. Based on the array, make HTML elements for each object where there's an `img` in it too.
3. When all of these HTML elements are created, attach it to the DOM, and call a final function.

This is what I have so far (truncated to get the point across):

**EDIT: code has changed a bit. scroll to bottom of question for link to current code.**

```
// based on one post, construct the html and return it
function getOneHtml(post, w) {
  console.log("getting one html");

  var outerDiv = $("<div>", {class: "brick"});
  outerDiv.width(w);

  var img = $("<img />");
  img.attr("src", post.img_src);

  img.on('load', function() {
    console.log("img loaded");
    var ratio = this.width / w;
    h = this.height / ratio;

    $(this).css({'height': h});

    // ...
    // ...
    // create the element

    // an alternative I'm using for now is directly append
    // the created HTML onto the page, but that results
    // in a kinda messy interface.
    return outerDiv[0].outerHTML;
  });
}

// queries an api and then calls callback after everything is done
function requestData(subreddit, callback) {
  // array of objects with link to image, post title, link to reddit
  posts = [];

  var w = $(window).innerWidth() / 3, 
      html = ''; // holds all of the inner HTML for all elements

  $.get("url here", function(data) {
    var arr = data.data.children;

    arr.forEach(function(res_post) {
      console.log("looping in requestData");
      // prepare a post object
      // ...
      // ...

      html += getOneHtml(post, w); // get the HTML for this post
    });

    // this should happen after everything else is done
    console.log("calling callback");
    callback(html);
  });
}

// complete the DOM
function makeWall(html) {
  console.log("making wall");
  // do stuff
}
```

Now the trace of the program in console is this:

```
looping in requestData
getting one html 
looping in requestData
getting one html 
... // bunch of times
calling callback
making wall
(20) img loaded
```

So now the problem is that the HTML isn't prepared until each image is loaded, and so it doesn't actually get attached to the DOM.

How can I make sure that things happen in order in which I want them to? I tried refactoring code into more of an async style but that didn't work (not my strongest point).

I also tried looking at `$.Deferred` but I don't understand it, and how to integrate it into my code.

Any help is appreciated.

**EDIT:**

I think it might help to see what I'm doing: http://karan.github.io/griddit/

When you load, I want the images to load first, and then fade in. Currently, they show up, then hide and then fade in. Here's the source: https://github.com/karan/griddit/blob/gh-pages/js/main.js.

Also, if you scroll down one or two pages, then scroll back up, some images show up behind others.

Comment: Did you read https://learn.jquery.com/code-organization/deferreds/ and http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/es6/promises/ ? Maybe that helps to understand promises better.

Comment: Does `getOneHtml` presently work ? What roles does `callback` , and `makeWall` perform ? Same, similar ?

Comment: @FelixKling Yes I did but as I said, I didn't *really* understand it.

Comment: @guest271314 Yes `getOneHtml` works just fine. In this case, `callback` is `makeWall`.

Comment: What is it that you don't understand?

Comment: How to integrate it into my code. I've seen some examples where they have one image, but not multiple. I think I've made my code complex enough that I can't really use promises without refactoring completely.

Comment: Perhaps missing something, what portion is not working ? If `makeWall` is placed at top of piece, including what to be done with `html`, can call `makeWall` where `callback` is presently positioned (substituting `makeWall` for `callback`) ? fwiw, Piece at original post, perhaps, _already_ utilizes (jquery) `deferred`, or `promise` `object` - at `,function(data)` of `$.get()`

Comment: Do you really need to wait for the images to all load before you insert anything in the DOM?  That is complicating your solution significantly and it will cause a significantly delay before anything is seen.  It will, of course, display instantly when it's finally ready though.  When forcing an image size, you can set just one dimension (h or w) and the image will scale the other automatically to maintain the original aspect ratio as long as you don't set both h and w.

Comment: @jfriend00 Unfortunately, freewall doesn't scale the image by itself.

Comment: @KaranGoel - I never said the image needed to be scaled by freewall (whatever that is).  I said that you do NOT have to wait for the image to load in order to scale it to a particular size.  If you already know that size, then there's no reason to wait for it to load and your whole algorithm could be a lot simpler.  I'm trying to make your life easier here.

Comment: @jfriend00 The problem is that I don't know the image size. I'm pulling those from an external API.

Comment: Why do you need to know the image size?

Comment: When building the DOM element. See this (might help) https://github.com/karan/griddit/blob/gh-pages/js/main.js#L11-L27

Comment: Apparently, I'm not making myself clear.  I've seen your code.  You don't need to know the aspect ratio.  You want to end up with a particular width that you pass into `getOneHtml()`. You can just set that width on the newly created image element without knowing the aspect ratio or any image dimension.  It will all work out with the same end result as you have now.

Comment: I tried that and for some reason, original image height is used. The height does not scale if I just set the width: http://snappy-app.com/s/show.php?pass=c0edf53e2bb1fa97cbd82838a27f7347

Comment: It works if the other dimension is NOT set.  See demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/Ju2Rs/

Comment: That seems to work sometimes now. I also added callback'd code but sometimes the height of `brick`s is set to 0.

Comment: @jfriend00 Apparently it's not working all the time. Sometimes, it just sets the height of outerDiv to 0 for some reason (probably because the image hasn't set by the time I set the width).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.done()`, as explained in [the jQuery API documentation](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.done/) on `.done()` specifically explains how to use `.done()` with `$.get()`.

It's as simple as:

```
$.get( "test.php" ).done(function() {
  alert( "$.get succeeded" );
});
```

#### Concretely...

As the API documentation link provided above indicates, you can daisy chain `.done()` calls together.

```
$.get(url,handler).done(function(){console.log('calling callback')},callback);
```

Comment: Images still loaded after `.done` is hit. So this isn't very helpful.

Comment: Actually, you can chain `.done()` calls unto each other!

Answer (score 0):

Note, Not certain about functionality of included plugins, i.e.g., `#grid` layout,
`css`, etc. image `width`, `height` and `#grid` layout not addressed, save for existing pieces re-composed in attempt at flow clarity.

Piece below solely to fulfill `// Do something when all dynamically created images have loaded` requirement. See console at jsfiddle

Note also, piece at jsfiddle format issue. In order to test piece, drew in 2 plugins from links at original post. Tried jsfiddle's `TidyUp` feature, which inserted linebreaks.

Piece may need some re-formatting; though current jsfiddle does provide `callback` functionality, as per original post. Again, see console. Thanks for sharing.

updated

```
      $(function() {
        // the name of the last added post 
        var last_added = '';
        // to control the flow of loading during scroll var scrollLoad = true;
        var q = 'cats'; 
        var callbacks = $.Callbacks();
        // callback,
        // Do something when all dynamically created images have loaded
        var callback = function (cb) {
          return console.log( cb||$.now() )
        };
        callbacks.add(callback);
        function getOneHtml(post, w, count){ 
          var img = $("<img>", {
                        "src" : post.img_src,
                        "width" : w 
                    });
        img.on('load', function(e) { 
          var ratio = e.target.width / w;
          h = e.target.height / ratio;
          $(e.target).css('height',h)
        });

        var link = $("<a>", {
                        "href" : post.permalink,
                        "target" : "_blank",
                        "html" : img 
                   });

        var outerDiv = $("<div>", {
                        "class" : "brick",
                        "style" : "width:" + w
                       });

        $.when($(outerDiv).appendTo("#grid"),
        $(link),
        count)
        .then(function(div, _link, _count) {
          // `image` `fadeIn`; adjustable
          $(_link).appendTo($(div)).hide(0).fadeIn(2000);
          return _count
        })
        .always(function(_count){
          callbacks.fireWith(window, [_count + " images appended to grid at " + $.now()])
        });
        };

        function requestData(subreddit,callback) {
        //array of objects with link to image, post title,link to reddit
          posts=[];
          var w = $(window).innerWidth() / 3;
          html = '';
          $.ajax({
            type : 'get',
            url : "http://api.reddit.com/r/" + subreddit + "/hot.json?&after=" + last_added,
            beforeSend : function () {
              $("#searchterm").addClass("loadinggif");
            },
            complete : function () {
              $("#searchterm").removeClass("loadinggif");
            },
            success : function (data) {
              var arr = data.data.children;
              var count = null;
              arr.forEach(function(res_post) {
                if(!res_post.data.is_self&&(/\.(gif|jpg|jpeg|tiff|png)$/i).test(res_post.data.url)) {
                  // `images` count
                  ++count;
                  var post = {
        'title' : res_post.data.title,
        'img_src': res_post.data.url,
        'name' : res_post.data.name,
        'permalink': 'http://reddit.com' + res_post.data.permalink
        };
             getOneHtml(post, w, count);
        }
        last_added = res_post.data.name;
        });
        scrollLoad = true;
        // callback,
        // Do something when all dynamically created images have loaded
        // see `console`; adjustable
        callbacks.fireWith( window, [$(".brick img").size() + " appended to grid, callback at " + $.now()]);
        }});
        }

                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                // function makeWall() {}
})
```

jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/guest271314/ggsY9/

Comment: So I had this, but you are assuming that I want a 50px x 50px image. I want to get the dimensions of an image, which means I need another `onload` callback.

Comment: The actual data within `data.data.children` ,`img` dimensions were not provided at original post. The piece at post and jsfiddle are only as an example _pattern_ or template; adjustable to meet the required image dimensions, or other parameters. The relevant portion of the piece above and jsfiddle is, perhaps, the portion where the `.brick` class `length` is stored as variable - which can be checked to determine if all images from `$.get()` call loaded - then proceed with `callback` function. Perhaps post actual `data.data.children` response, and jsfiddle demonstrating issue at original post ?

Comment: I think it might help to see what I'm doing: http://karan.github.io/griddit/

When you load, I want the images to load first, and then fade in. Currently, they show up, then hide and then fade in. Here's the source: https://github.com/karan/griddit/blob/gh-pages/js/main.js.

Also, if you scroll down one or two pages, then scroll back up, some images show up behind others.

Comment: Thanks. Perhaps helpful to add actual `append` part to original post ? As it appears currently, viewers of this Question do not have that piece available to look at (unless read above comment) - where `img` appended to document. Whether "messy" or not (read: subjective ?), having that portion available may alter approaches of Answers provided ? Note, Appears _more than `20` images_ are appended to document ?  Will glance at repo, original post, again. Thanks for sharing